# How to get id of current participant from within the angular frontend of hyperledger-composer app?

Tags: angular, hyperledger-composer

My question is on hyperledger-composer:

Within a transaction processor function, one can get the id of the current participant as follows:

```
let currentParticipant = getCurrentParticipant();

let participantId = currentParticipant.getFullyQualifiedIdentifier();
```

But how can I get the id of the current participant from within the angular app?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think is possible to retrieve this information directly from angular.

You can retrieve the participant based on the card that you use to submit the transaction.

I suggest you to expose APIs using Hyperledger Composer-Rest-Server and invoke them directly from your angular app.

Here the official documentation. https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/integrating/getting-started-rest-api

Comment: Thank you for your comment ... in order to retrieve the card of the current user, I need the participant id of the current, though, don't I?

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do. Because if you submit a transaction, you should already know who is the participant.
Otherwise, another possibility is to emit an event (with the identity of the participant) every time that the chaincode is invoked. In this case you can create an application which could listen the event and capture the data. 
Here you can find more information.
https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/business-network/publishing-events

Answer (score 0):

This is a Dirty hack but It works for me.

Try pinging`localhost:3000/api/system/ping` this will ping the current user and returns the participant user.

As mentioned in the previous answer, Use composer-rest-server